# Switch case in Android app

Tags: android, switch-statement, case

Here is the code that supposed to open a dialog box when i press the About button in my min activity page. But nothing really happens. : /

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        View continueButton = findViewById(R.id.continue_button);
        continueButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        View newgameButton = findViewById(R.id.new_button);
        continueButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        View aboutButton = findViewById(R.id.about_button);
        continueButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        View exitButton = findViewById(R.id.exit_button);
        continueButton.setOnClickListener(this);




public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.continue_button:
                break;
        case R.id.about_button:     
                Intent i = new Intent(this, About.class);
                startActivity(i);
                break;
        case R.id.new_button: 
                openNewGameDialog(); 
                break;
        case R.id.exit_button:
                finish();
                break;  


        }       
    }
```

Main Activity XML

```
<LinearLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:background="@color/background"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:padding="30dip"
   android:orientation="horizontal" >
<LinearLayout
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_gravity="center" >
 <TextView
   android:text="@string/main_title"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_gravity="center"
   android:layout_marginBottom="25dip"
   android:textSize="24.5sp" />
 <Button
   android:id="@+id/continue_button"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="@string/continue_label" />
 <Button
   android:id="@+id/new_button"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="@string/new_game_label" />
 <Button
   android:id="@+id/about_button"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="@string/about_label" />
 <Button
   android:id="@+id/exit_button"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="@string/exit_label" />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Example of a button: About

About Activity

```
public class About extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.about);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.about, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

About XML

```
<ScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:padding="10dip" >
<TextView
android:id="@+id/about_content"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/about_text" />
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: post whole activity code

Comment: please add certain code of your activity . so that i can help you

Comment: ok, here is the code.

Comment: @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.main);
  
  View continueButton = findViewById(R.id.continue_button);
  continueButton.setOnClickListener(this);
  View newgameButton = findViewById(R.id.new_button);
  continueButton.setOnClickListener(this);
  View aboutButton = findViewById(R.id.about_button);
  continueButton.setOnClickListener(this);
  View exitButton = findViewById(R.id.exit_button);
  continueButton.setOnClickListener(this);
 }

Comment: Sorry for the mess . I am pretty new in this

Comment: Check the Edit I made to my response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's your problem:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    View continueButton = findViewById(R.id.continue_button);
    continueButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    View newgameButton = findViewById(R.id.new_button);
    **newgameButton**.setOnClickListener(this);

    View aboutButton = findViewById(R.id.about_button);
    **aboutButton**.setOnClickListener(this);

    View exitButton = findViewById(R.id.exit_button);
    **exitButton**.setOnClickListener(this);
}
```

Only your 'continueButton' has an onClickListener registered...

Also:
It is good practice to also have a default case in a switch statement which gets executed if none of the cases hold. Add a default case with a log message or something and see if it gets executed.

Comment: Totally, something which would just tell you what the value of `v.GetId()` is, like `log.d("someActivity", someConvertToStringMethod( v.GetId() ) )`.

Comment: Great. Got it. Regarding the Log.id(CONSTANT, msg) - seems i can get the handle of it. If i want to get lets say the output for the button i pressed, lets say i pressed the continueButton, what should i write inside the Log.d? (I mean instead the 'msg' ). And also where do i see the result? (i know it is in the logcat but there are so many output there... )

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure your activity implements View.OnClickListener interface.

Secondly, try to add @Override before the public void onClick(View view) { } method declaration. If this does not help, try to add a log statement at top of the onClick method, for example logging the ID of the view, and compare it to the ones you're trying to match it against.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i can say, you need to call `button.setOnClickListener(this);` in your activity onCreate method